# Swift - Firestore orders array wrong by retrieving

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a weird problem where I am retrieving data but somehow Firestore retrieves documents in the wrong order and I have no idea why.

This is my code (look at the `print`-tests for a better understanding):

```
func getWishes (){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    var counter = 0

    for list in self.dataSourceArray {
        print(list.name) // -> right order
    }

    for list in self.dataSourceArray {
        db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document(list.name).collection("wünsche").getDocuments() { ( querySnapshot, error) in
            print(list.name) // -> wrong order
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                // create new Wish array
                var wList: [Wish] = [Wish]()
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let documentData = document.data()
                    let wishName = documentData["name"]
                    wList.append(Wish(withWishName: wishName as! String, checked: false))
                }

                self.dataSourceArray[counter].wishData = wList
                counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my [git](https://github.com/chriskonnerth/Wishlist)

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more clear about what exactly the "right order" is? Actual data is helpful. I find it kind of odd that you're populating `self.dataSourceArray` inside a loop over `self.dataSourceArray`. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: dataSourceArray contains a `structs` called Wishlists. In another `function` I already retrieve these Wishlists with their name and image. But I am trying to fill them with the function above. `dataSourceArray` is already ordered by another parameter

Comment: @DougStevenson I included my git in my question, maybe that helps

Comment: can you make it a class ?

Comment: why would that make a difference?  I feel like a `struct` is easier in my case. But nevertheless I don't get why the two `print`- tests differ. That makes no sense to me

Comment: The firebase closure is asynchronous and the outside loop is going to execute WAY faster than the data is returned from Firebase (and the data becomes valid inside the closure) which may affect ordering. What your attempting here is unclear and we don't know what your Firestore structure looks like. Can you clarify what your trying to do and provde a snapshot of your Firebase structure?

Comment: This is the second time you've asked the same question. Please stick to the original question as asking the same question repeatedly spreads out the information.

Comment: @Jay thanks for your help. I figured out a way to solve that problem